# assertion failure with message: no balance object found

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, transfer

This error message occurs when trying to do a transfer:

`assertion failure with message: no balance object found`

What causes it and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 4):

This error message is caused because you are trying to transfer a token that you do not own and have never owned. You have no balance, which is not the same as having a balance of zero.

Usually you would get this error if you make a mistake where you think you have tried to transfer a token, but you have accidentally transferred a token that doesn't exist. Either because you are:

1. Calling the wrong contract.
2. Have a typo in the symbol name.
3. Have the wrong number of decimal places (precision) for the token.

Comment: I got this because I had literally a balance of 0 system token available.